# Shared library vs. opening a process performance

Tags: python, c++, process

I have a certain base of Python code (a Flask server). I need the server to perform a performance-critical operation, which I've decided to implement in C++. However, as the C++ part has other dependencies, trying out `ctypes` and `boost.python` yielded no results (not found symbols, other libraries even when setting up the environment, etc., basically, there were *problems*). I believe a suitable alternative would be for me to just compile the C++ part into an executable (a single function/procedure is required) and run it from python using `commands` or `subprocess`, communicating through `stdin/out` for example. The only thing I'm worried about is that this will slow down the procedure enough to matter and since I'm unable to create a shared object library, calling its function from python directly, I cannot benchmark the speedup.

When I compile the C++ code into an executable and run it with some sample data, the program takes `~5s` to run. This does not account for opening the process from python, nor for passing data between the processes.

The question is: **How big of a speedup can one expect by using ctypes/boost with a SO compared to creating a new process to run the procedure?** If I regard the number to be big enough, it would motivate me to solve the encountered problems, basically, I'm asking if it's *worth it*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're struggling with creating binding using Boost.Python, you can manually expose your API via c-functions and use them via FFI.

Here's a simple example, which briefly explains my idea. At first, you create a shared library, but add some extra functions here, which in the example I put into `extern "C"` section. It's necessary to use `extern "C"` since otherwise function names will be mangled and their actual names are likely to be different from those you've declared:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

#ifdef __GNUC__
#define EXPORT __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#else // __GNUC__
#error "Unsupported compiler"
#endif // __GNUC__

class data_processor {
public:
  data_processor() = default;

  void process_data(const std::uint8_t *data, std::size_t size) {
    std::printf("processing %zu bytes of data at %p\n", size, data);
  }
};

extern "C" {
EXPORT void *create_processor() {
  return new data_processor();
}

EXPORT void free_processor(void *data) {
  delete static_cast<data_processor *>(data);
}

EXPORT void process_data(void *object, const std::uint8_t *data, const std::uint32_t size) {
  static_cast<data_processor *>(object)->process_data(data, size);
}
}
```

Then you create function bindings in python. As you can see function declarations are almost the same as they are in the cpp file below. I used built-in types only (like `void *`, `uint8_t` and anything, but I believe FFI allows you to declare and use custom structs as well):

```py
from cffi import FFI

mylib_api = FFI()
mylib_api.cdef("""
    void *create_processor();
    void free_processor(void *object);
    void process_data(void *object, const uint8_t *data, uint32_t size);
""")
mylib = mylib_api.dlopen("mylib.so-file-location")

processor = mylib.create_processor()
try:
    buffer = b"buffer"
    mylib.process_data(processor, mylib_api.from_buffer("uint8_t[]", python_buffer=buffer), len(buffer))
finally:
    mylib.free_processor(processor)
```

And that's basically it.

In my opinion inter-processing is going to be the last resort when nothing else works since:

- you need to put a lot of efforts implementing details of your communication protocol, either if you use something popular, there could be a lot of issues, especially from c++-side;
- inter-process communication is generally more expensive in terms of processor time.